# how to print an array forward and backward based on boolean flag true/false using single for loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Arr = {"apple" , "orange" , "pineapple"};
If (boolean)flag = true :
o/p -
pineapple
orange
apple
Else
o/p -
apple
orange
pineapple

I tried using while, how to implement it using for?

```
public static void printArrayElements(boolean flag , String arr[]) {
        int i=0;
        int arrSize = arr.length;
        if(flag == true) {
            i = arrSize-1;
        }else {
            i = 0 ;
        }
        while( flag ? i >= 0 : i <arrSize ) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            if(flag) {
                i--;
            }else {
                i++ ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can slim down your code:     `String[] arr = {"apple" , "orange" , "pineapple"};
    boolean reverse = true ;
    int i = reverse ? arr.length-1 : 0 ;
    while( reverse ? i >= 0 : i < arr.length ) {
        System.out.println( arr[ reverse ? i-- : i++ ] );
    }`  https://ideone.com/xWMuQX

Comment: why not use a simple `if` and two loops? ( alternative: `for (int i=0, j=arr.length-1; j>=0; i++, j--) System.out.println(arr[flag ? j : i]);`  ) (( I would call the flag `reversed` or similar ))

Comment: My apologies , need the solution using single for loop

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[flag ? (arr.length - 1 - i) : i]);
}
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/aytDYs).

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this with a simple for loop. The idea is to iterate over the array forward base on the boolean flag. If it is forward iterating array with** `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` **else if it is backward** `for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Refer the code below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"apple", "orange", "pineapple"};
       
        printArray(arr, true);
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        printArray(arr, false);
       
    }

    private static void printArray(String[] arr, boolean forward) {
        if (forward) {
            System.out.println("Printing array forward:");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing array backward:");
            for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Refer to the working code [here.](https://onlinegdb.com/pUnrCwudF)**

Comment: My apologies , need the solution using single for loop